# Ionicframework slide box ng-repeat length error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have setup a tabbed navigation in ionicframework.
The first tab is a listing of sections, on clicking a section you are taken to a second tab showing all the information in that page in an ion-slide-box.
I have an ng-repeat on the ion-slide.

I have found that when navigating around between sections and pages (as you would when reading a book), I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property length of #<HTMLCollection> which has only a getter
at ionic.views.Slider.ionic.views.View.inherit.initialize.kill (ionic.bundle.js:8486)
at ionic.bundle.js:54326
at Scope.$get.Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:23419)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$destroy (ionic.bundle.js:23039)
at destroyViewEle (ionic.bundle.js:46792)
at Object.IonicModule.factory.ionicViewSwitcher.create.switcher.cleanup (ionic.bundle.js:46639)
at transitionComplete (ionic.bundle.js:46580)
at HTMLElement.completeOnTransitionEnd (ionic.bundle.js:46559)
at HTMLElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11713)
```

Does anybody know what this means?

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this existing codepen ? 
http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/Kcxaw

```
      <ion-slide ng-repeat="slide in data.slides | filter:{viewable : true}">
        <div ng-include src="slide.template"></div>
      </ion-slide>
```

Comment: This is a nice codepen, but could you please explain what you mean? I'm getting the same error, but I do not have any dynamic slides.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in ionic which at least existed until 1.0.0-rc5.
It is definitely fixed in 1.0.0.

Old line causing exception:

```
  // reset slides so no refs are held on to
  slides && (slides.length = []);
```

Fixed version (see [github](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/views/sliderView.js#L553-L554)):

```
  // reset slides so no refs are held on to
  slides && (slides = []);
```